# Fastify get item by title always returning raw JSON as null

Tags: fastify

I'm just starting with Fastify and ran into an issue where I started creating a get request to get an item by its title, but it keeps giving me a response of `null` when I try and log the `request.body`.

**My get request:**

```
// Get points by title
fastify.route({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/pointz/title',
    handler: (request, reply) => {
        return request.body
    }
})
```

**My get request in postman (as code):**

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/pointz/title' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "title": "test"
}'
```

[Screenshot of my input and output in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQOnM.png)

The expected result would be that the request returns a body that contains the JSON that's being sent, so I can change the code to access `request.body.title` with a return value of `test`.

***UPDATE:***
Found a workaround for now. If I change the GET request to a POST request it works just like it's supposed to. I question however if this is considered good practice.

Comment: The GET method can't have a body by spec and Fastify ignore it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in this GitHub Issue [GET request validated scheme body?](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/1737)
the `body` should not be send in GET request, [a datailed answer about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/3309466)
and fastify ignore it by default.

But legacy code does, and if you need to support it, you have to consume the raw request:

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })
fastify.get('/', async (req) => {
  let body = ''
  for await (const data of req.raw) {
    body += data.toString()
  }
  return body
})
fastify.listen(3000)
```

Then your `curl` command will works as expected.

```js
const got = require('got')
got.get('http://localhost:3000/', {
  json: { hello: 'world' },
  allowGetBody: true
}).then(res => {
  console.log('Returned = ' + res.body)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!